# How can i parse/extract the text of date and time between two tags?

Tags: c#, winforms

I dont know how to use htmlagilitypack so im using indexof and substring.

This is an example of a part of the text in the string i have :

```
<span style=color:#000099;>כתב: Snakeye   בתאריך: 15.02.14  שעה: 02:02</span>
```

There are many parts of this lines in the text and i want only to get this part each time:

```
בתאריך: 15.02.14  שעה: 02:02
```

Sometimes in some cases the format of the text part i want to get it from look like this:

```
<span style=color:#000099;>כתב: כוח שושנה   בתאריך: 14.02.14  שעה: 15:25</span>
```

And again i want to get only the part: בתאריך: 14.02.14  שעה: 15:25

This is the code i tried so far:

```
private void ExtractDateTime(string text)
        {
            List<string> allText = new List<string>();
            List<string> extractedText = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                allText.Add(text);
            }
            int startIndex = 0;
            int endIndex = 0;
            int position = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                string startTag = "<span style=color:#000099;>";
                string endTag = "בתאריך";
                startIndex = allText[i].IndexOf(startTag);
                while (startIndex > 0)
                {
                    endIndex = allText[i].IndexOf(endTag, startIndex);
                    if (endIndex == -1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    string t = allText[i].Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + endTag.Length);
                    extractedText.Add(t);
                    position = endIndex + endTag.Length;
                    startIndex = allText[i].IndexOf(startTag, position);
                }
            }
        }
```

And i call this method in the constructor:

```
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1255);
page = client.DownloadString("http://rotter.net/scoopscache.html");
ExtractDateTime(page);
```

But the result im getting in the method the variable t contain:

```
<span style=color:#000099;>כתב: Noam   בתאריך
<span style=color:#000099;>כתב: ברזאני   בתאריך
```

Not what i wanted. How can i fix it ?

This is how i used it with regex:

```
private void ExtractDateTime(string text)
        {
            string input = "<span style=color:#000099;>כתב: אלירן-אביטל   בתאריך: 14.02.14  שעה: 14:40</span>";
            string pattern1 = "^<.*>(?'hebrew'.*)<.*>$";

            Regex expr1 = new Regex(pattern1);
            Match match1 = expr1.Match(input);
            string hebrew = match1.Groups["hebrew"].Value;

            string pattern2 = @"\d\d:\d\d\s+:.*:[^\s]*";
            pattern2 = @"[^\s]*:[^:]*:\s+\d\d:\d\d";
            Regex expr2 = new Regex(pattern2);
            Match match2 = expr2.Match(hebrew);
            string results = match2.Value;           
        }
```

Its working but only for the specific input variable string. How do i make it for all the rest places in my text that i want to extract the text from ? There are many places like this input string variable in the text.

Comment: Have you considered regex for this task? (regular expressions)

Comment: Vitaliy i tried im updating my question showing what i did so far using regex.

Comment: Updated my question with using regex and why its not completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
var client = new System.Net.WebClient();

client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1255);

var page = client.DownloadString("http://rotter.net/scoopscache.html");

var re = new Regex(@"<span style=color:#000099;>(.+?)</span>");

var matches = re.Matches(page)
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(_ => _.Groups[1].Value)
                .ToArray();

/*
    'matches' contains the matched strings 
*/
```